# Improve Quality of CSS3 Filter

Tags: css

Is there a way to improve the quality of CSS3 filters when using large images?

Here you can see which image I am using:
[image: flickr – eleven Wolfgang Staudt]
*source: [flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/wolfgangstaudt/2298693122/)*

The image was styled as follows:

```
.blur {
    filter: blur(5px);
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    -moz-filter: blur(5px);
    -o-filter: blur(5px);
    -ms-filter: blur(5px);
}
```

However the gradients turn in many ugly "increments".

Please have a look:
[image]

I've created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3DRjF/) for demonstration purposes.

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue on a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)? I dont see that problem here

Comment: Are you using any transitions on hover?

Comment: @GiovanniSilveira Thanks for the hint. Here you are: http://jsfiddle.net/3DRjF/

Comment: @Donte'Trumble No, not yet.

Comment: Is it because the image is not actually being displayed in it's true ratio? http://jsfiddle.net/3qc82/

Comment: Looks promising, @GiovanniSilveira.
I will have a closer look on it tomorrow. I will give some more feedback then.

Comment: Even if you turn off the blur, you will see artifacts, specially when resizing and changing the ratio. +1 for @GiovanniSilveira